# How can I change my default Python version, that if I type python in the terminal python 3 gets executed?

Tags: python, version

Can somebody help me? I tried to change my python version with the alias but I got a "permission denied". What can I do? I'm on a mac.

Answer (score 0):

Put "sudo" at the start of your command to get around "permission denied". This will give you superuser privileges on your machine. Use this power with care.

[More on sudo](http://%20https://scriptingosx.com/2018/04/demystifying-root-on-macos-part-2-the-sudo-command/)

Comment: I just did it. I thought it was way more complicated.